# Executing "cp" from plink script results in error

Tags: linux, command-line, plink

I'm trying to run several commands on may Linux VMs via plink.

I created following plink command file:

```
cp /home/user/scropt.sh /tmp ; chmod a+x /tmp/script.sh ; /tmp/script.sh
```

I run plink like this:

```
plink -ssh -pw <password> -l <user> -m <path to command file> <host>
```

Login is ok but then I get an error:

```
"cp" isn't allowed to be executed.
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Is that the exact error you get? - I'd expect something about not finding a command called cp.

Comment: @djsmiley2k No - that's all I get as an error. Why would "cp" not exist ?

Comment: Looks like you might be connecting to an SSH server that has restricted permission. Maybe it is using a Jail or something.

Comment: @gogators that would be odd since I'm allowed to execute "cp" when I login with the same user via an interactive ssh session.